# rendering wrong view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view

There is a simple code:

```
def new
  if !logged_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render "new_failed"}
      return
    end
  end

  article = Article.find params[:id]
  @comment = article.comments.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

When user in not logged in, "new_failed" should be rendered, but, actually, "new" action is rendered.

When i put the logged_in? to end of method:

```
def new
  if !logged_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render "new_failed"}
      return
    end
  end

  article = Article.find params[:id]
  @comment = article.comments.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.js
  end
end
```

It works correctly.

What a strange behavior is it ? Can anyone explain it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the return inside the respond_to.
If you do it like this it works (here).

```
if !logged_in?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render "new_failed"}
  end
  return
end
```